# How to use crypto-config file for fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the crypto-config file to create the keypairs, using cryptogen tool. How i can use same config file for creating the keypair using fabric-CA please suggest me if its possible to use same config ?

Answer (score 2):

The crypto-config.yaml file is unique to the cryptogen tool.

Assuming you have started a fabric-ca service then you can use the fabric-ca-client cli, or connect with a SDK to create identities programatically.

The fabric-ca-client documentation is [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clientcli.html) and the user guide is [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html).

The fabcar sample in [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) has examples for Javascript, Typescript and Java SDKs for enrolling an Admin Identity and then using that Admin identity to register and enroll other users.